# How to echo exec output into a HTML table

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, tags

My HTML file has the following CSS:

```
<style>
#circleRed {
background: #ff0000;
width: 15px;
height: 15px;
border-radius: 50%;
}

#circleGreen {
background: #00ff00;
width: 15px;
height: 15px;
border-radius: 50px;
}
</style>

<div id="circleRed"></div>
<div id="circleGreen"></div>
```

And on the same HTML file I have a PHP script:

```
<?php
function ReturnError($res)
{
 switch ($res)
 {
 case "0":
 return " No errors";

case "-1":
return " Video not found. This could be due to incorrect video format.";

case "-2":
return " Video file could not be opened.";

case "-3":
return "il_client failed to initiate. Might be due to resource issue, e.g. not enough RAM space.";

case "-4":
return "OMX player failed to initiate. Please try rebooting the PI, or replace the PI.";
 }
}

$command = "ssh -p 97 -i /var/www/html/test1.rsa pi@192.168.xxx.xxx tail -1 /var/log/playlog.csv";
$output = exec($command);

 if($idx = strripos($output,','))//Get the last index of ',' in the output string
{
 $ErrorCode = substr($output,$idx + 1,(strlen($output) - $idx) - 1);//using the found index, get the error code using substring
 $Playlist = substr($output, 0, $idx + 1);//Get the rest of the output string, minus the error code 
 echo "Test: <p></p>Currently Playing: ".$Playlist.ReturnError($ErrorCode);//The ReturnError function just replaces the error code with a custom error
}

?>
```

Which outputs:

```
Test:
Currently Playing: 2018-03-27 09:41:36,NM_Test.h264, No errors
```

How can I instead echo the output into a HTML table, like so:

```
+--------+----------+-----------+-------+-------------+
| Status | Name     | Date/time | Video | Error Status|
+--------+----------+-----------+-------+-------------+
```

Depending on which switch statement is executed if:

- Case "0" : Status should print green circle
- Cases from "-1" & "-4" : Status should print red circle

So something like:

```
+-------------+--------+-------------------+-------------+-------------+
| Status      | Name   | Date/time         | Video       | Error Status|
+-------------+------------------------------------------+-------------+
|#circleGreen | Test   |2018-03-27 09:41:36| NM_Test.h264| No Errors   |
+-------------+--------+-------------------+-------------+-------------+
```

**Update**

Based on a user's feedback I have tried to use explode by:

```
$array = explode(',',$output);
echo $array[0];
echo $array[1];
echo $array[2];
```

And then I can use HTML table tags to output each array as a table, but with this method I can't figure out how to achieve what I'm currently doing with the if statement?

Comment: Try exploding the whole output of exec on the base of **,** and use it where ever you want.You can display output array's indexes in table

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion, I'll give it a go.

Comment: Based on your feedback, I used explode to retrieve the data by: `var_dump( explode(',', $output) );`  and then echoed it by `echo "<table><tr>".implode("</tr><tr>",array_map(function($a) {return "<td>".implode("</td><td>",explode(" ",trim($a)))."</td>";},explode(",",$output)))."</tr></table>";` but the output isn't what I'm trying to achieve. How can I better display each index of the array inside a table?

Answer (score 0):

you can add in your file php like this

```html
<table border="1">
<tr>
 <th>Nom etudiant</th>
 <th>Prenom</th>
 <th>CIN</th>
 <th>Note tp</th>
 <th>Note ds</th>
 <th>Note exam</th>
</tr>
<?php
$sql5 = "select * from `etudiant` , `etudier` where (`id_section`='$id_section' and `etudier`.`id_etudiant`=`etudiant`.`cin` and `etudier`.`id_matiere`='$id_matiere');";
 if($req2 = mysql_query($sql5)){
  while($data2 = mysql_fetch_array($req2)){
        
   ?>
<tr>
 <td><?php echo $data2['nom'] ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $data2['prenom'] ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $data2['cin'] ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $data2['note_tp'] ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $data2['note_ds'] ?></td>
 <td><?php echo $data2['note_exam'] ?></td>
 <?php 
 $link="ajoute_note_etudiant.php?id_etudiant=".$data2['cin']."&id_matiere=".$id_matiere;
 ?>
 <td><a href="<?php echo $link ?>">Modifer</a></td>

 <?php 
 }}else{
  echo "da5let";
 }?>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I'm a little confused on how I can use sql in my solution?